# How to recognize order before saving in the backend ? - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order

I would like to post some data in **admin order** create form and check if it exists and is set if not throw an exception.

I was thinking about `adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data` event, but it is called several times. I think it would be nice to have some sort of event before the admin order is saved and check if this data exists.

Comment: Maybe is "sales_order_save_before". Magento use it in \Magento\Payment\Observer\SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver for set canCreditmemo flag.

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin for Sales/Model/Order by putting smth like this in your module, in di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order">
    <plugin name="YOUR NAME" type="Your-Module\Sales\Plugin\Sales\Model\Order" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Then, in Order.php create

```
public function beforeSave(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject)
{
$subject->getData() 
// this is your order Data before saving it
}
```